# execute system command from c function and bring back the control back to main

Tags: c

I am executing LSF and Perl files (which have specific function related to automation of test cases) from my c function. I want to execute the system() command and dont want to wait till the process of execution of the files is complete, instead I want the control to fall back to the main c program to continue with the execution of the program and leave the task to be carried out by the linux execution engine.can someone help me with this.

I have attached the code below:

```
sprintf(String, "/home/teproj/nxp90884/CellDesign/AN_DFIIToCdl.lsf %s %s %s %s %s", res, cel, tmp, frc, upd);
 system(String);
```

Comment: You should use `snprintf`, not `sprintf`

Comment: Your question is operating system specific. On Linux, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and learn how to use [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc etc...

Answer (score 2):

Since `system()` forks a shell to run your command line, you can just append an ampersand (`&`) to the command line to make the shell run the command in the background.

That's the quick and dirty approach. The clean approach is of course to do the process management yourself, using `fork()` and `exec()` calls.

Comment: It's a nice hack, but what if the main function is actually the background process and the command OP is trying to execute is the interactive one?

Answer (score 1):

You can `fork` and call the `execve` system call in the child process, continuing with your original job in the parent process(or vice-versa)

Comment: No; no need to `fork` and call `system` in child, but `fork` and call `execve` in child!

Answer (score 0):

To run a task in the background you need to start a new thread. `fork()` is one friend, the `pthread` family another.

Example using `fork`:

```
process = fork();

if (process < 0){
   //fork error
   perror("fork");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (process == 0){
    // Child process. You can either use one of the exec functions:

    execl("/home/teproj/nxp90884/CellDesign/AN_DFIIToCdl.lsf" "AN_DFIIToCdl.lsf", res, cel, tmp,frc,upd, NULL);

    // or system + exit.
    sprintf(String, "c %s %s %s %s %s", res, cel, tmp, frc, upd);
    system(String);
    exit(0); // to terminate the child.
} else {
  // Main thread. Continue executing
}
```

Best practice is to choose one of the exec functions in this case.